# how to send net-snmp traps from "C"

Tags: c, snmp

I need to write code to send traps from my application (using net-snmp APIs)
Anyone has a simple sample code to do that?
Thanks,
Gil

Answer (score 6):

[Net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/) contains a command-line application called **snmptrap** which can be used to generate traps. You can take a look at a tutorial [here](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptrap) and you can download its source from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.5/). **\net-snmp-5.5\apps\snmptrap.c** is 395 lines long, so it can be considered as a 'simple sample code'.